# remove duplicate records in python

Tags: python, duplicates

How can I remove duplicate records in the following form by using Python 3?
For the variable, "string":

```
string = '{"information": [{"ID":"1111","name":"Smith","Age":"20"},       
             {"Age":"31","name":"Jane","ID":"2222"},
             {"ID":"1111","name":"Smith","Age":"20"},
             {"ID":"1111","Age":"20","name":"Smith"},
             {"ID":"3333","Age":"28","name":"Sam"}]}'
```

Required output after removing duplicates:

```
[{"ID":"1111","name":"Smith","Age":"20"}, 
 {"ID":"2222","Age":"31","name":"Jane"},
 {"ID":"3333","Age":"28","name":"Sam"}]
```

I'd be grateful if you guys can help me out.

Comment: "I want to use only "re" package and built-in functions for pre-processing this data" Why? Using `re` for this sounds like a horrible idea, and built-in functions would mean using `eval` to parse the list, which is equally horrible. Instead, I'd strongly suggest using `json` to parse the list, then a dict to find duplicates.

Comment: Using `re` would be foolish.  You should use json.loads

Comment: Why record which id is '1111' is not in required output? As I understand, duplicates must be removed. Or should dictionaries which have duplicates removed?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I just updated the required output.

Answer (score 5):

Using `re` for this sounds like a horrible idea, and only built-in functions would mean using `eval` to parse the list, which is equally horrible.

Instead, I'd suggest using `json` to parse the string, then a `collections.Counter` to find duplicates, and finally a simple list comprehension to re-create the unique dictionaries from the (made hashable) keys in the Counter.

```
>>> import json, collections
>>> lst = json.loads(string)["information"]
>>> c = collections.Counter(frozenset(d.items()) for d in lst)
>>> [dict(x) for x in c if c[x] == 1]
[{'ID': '2222', 'name': 'Jane', 'Age': '31'},
 {'Age': '28', 'name': 'Sam', 'ID': '3333'}]
```

If you really, *really* want to use just `re`, you could try the following: 1. use a regex to `search` the `[...]` list; b) use another regex to `findall` the `{...}` groups within the previous match; (iii) within all *those* parts, use yet another regex to get all the `'...': '...'` bits; finally, use those to recreate the dictionaries and proceed as above. (However, it really does not make any sense using regex for parsing a structure like this.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas if you like.  Let it be said again that you probably shouldn't use eval, as it can be dangerous.

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(string)['information']).drop_duplicates(keep=False).to_dict('records')
```

Output

```
[{'ID': '2222', 'name': 'Jane', 'Age': '31'}, {'ID': '3333', 'name': 'Sam', 'Age': '28'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to safely evaluate string and then use set comprehension to uniquefy dictionaries converted into tuples and then convert those unique tuples back to dictionaries:

```
import ast

d = ast.literal_eval(string)

uniq = {tuple(sorted(record.items())) for record in d['information']}

result = [dict(item) for item in uniq]

# result -> [{'Age': '28', 'ID': '3333', 'name': 'Sam'}, {'Age': '31', 'ID': '2222', 'name': 'Jane'}, {'Age': '20', 'ID': '1111', 'name': 'Smith'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string = """{"information": [{"ID":"1111","name":"Smith","Age":"20"},       
             {"Age":"31","name":"Jane","ID":"2222"},
             {"ID":"1111","name":"Smith","Age":"20"},
             {"ID":"1111","Age":"20","name":"Smith"},
             {"ID":"3333","Age":"28","name":"Sam"}]}"""
exec('d='+string)
l = []
for r in d['information']:
    if r not in l:
        l.append(r)
print(l)
```